# Nnetar and arima functions. Does it read descending or ascending?

Tags: r

I have a CSV with the earliest data being at the top and the latest data being at the bottom.

If I run `auto.arima(data)` or `nnetar(data)`, is the calculation based on `1st entry = yt` and `2nd entry = y(t-1)` ... etc.?

If not please advise how to invert the data in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto.arima` expects `1st entry = y(t)`, `2nd entry = y(t+1)`... which means earliest data is first, followed by newer data. For example, `1-Jan` and then `2-Jan` so on.

In case you want to invert the time series, use `?rev` function.

Comment: you can plot a trivial time series like - 

`fit <- auto.arima(sin(1:40/40))` 

`plot(forecast(fit,h=20))`